# Wifi Direct Group Owner Intention

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Can someone explain me how android performs Group Owner Negotiation?
In particular how does android perform GO request/reply exchange?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can decide who becomes group owner by this line of code :

```
config.groupOwnerIntent = x;
```

Where x is from 0 to 15. 0 representing least intention to become owner while 15 represents the highest.

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pConfig.html#groupOwnerIntent)

Comment: Hi, let suppose we have 2 devices which automatically choose a random groupOwnerIntent, how does android make comparison beteen them, in order to elect as GO whichone with highest groupOwnerIntent?

Comment: I assume you mean that you have not set groupOwnerIntent on any of the devices. In this case owner is chosen randomly

Comment: You are rigth, but let suppose I want to set for the device1 a GO intent equal to 10 and for the device2 a GO intent equal to 9. Now if the device1 tries to connect to the device2, how android does decide which device is more suitable to become GO?

Comment: device1, most probably.

Comment: Ok, I know that according to the protocol a GO negotiation Request/ GO negotiation Response/GO negotiation Confirmation exchange between Device1 and Device2 should exist.I known that, always according to the protocol, Device 1 should become GO.My question is : how does Device 2 acquire its own GO intent in order to compare with whichone received by Device1?

Comment: As far as I know, it does not. You just use 15 if you wish to become owner and 0 otherwise. Also see that for above 4.2 if a previous group was formed the device which was owner previously will be the new owner.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no comparison between the two GO intent?No negotiation?

Comment: If you want to know what exactly happens I suggest you read this : http://www.google.com/patents/US20110225305

Comment: I know how protocol of wifi direct for GO election works. I need to implement it and, to do that, I need to know when and where set (in my code) in a correct way, GO intent for D2. I wish to know if android do that and what method I have to use.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I always assumed that the device which others connect to is the owner.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Intention before connecting to the other WiFi p2p enabled devices. You do not need to do anything else regarding the GO negotiation. It means that you perform the discovery and then, you request to connect to one of the peers that is discovered. Then it would be the android API responsibility to perform the negotiation phase.

Comment: I know how to set the intention of the device which sends the request. Unfortunately, I didnt't find a way to set the intention of the device that receives the request, before it receives the request. Do you know how can I do?

Comment: What kind of request exactly? There is one request in WiFi Direct which is "request to join a group" that would be performed after GO negotiation. Regarding the intention, it should be set in all devices before starting discovery and GO negotiation

Comment: Hi Naser, from tests carried out I 've found that, for non-rooted devices, I can manage only the intention of the device sending the request. Once the receiver device receives the request it will use its own default intention. The reason is that the only way to change the default intention is by using the connect() method which works like explained here:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html#connect(android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.Channel, android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pConfig, android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener)