# Customized channel wifi direct

Tags: channel, wifi-direct

Can anyone tell me, is there any option to customize wifi direct channels? I need to customize it not only between ch1, ch6 and ch11, but also in another channels selected by me. How can I do that?

Comment: Yes brother, I just experimented with Galaxy Tab (rooted), and it works nicely. THANKS A LOT AGAIN :). Is there any option to fix the "group owner" of a wifi direct communication? please let me know...

Comment: Yes there is. It is done in the JAVA code by setting config.groupOwnerIntent. Check the answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23470768/wifi-direct-group-owner-intention. If this didnt help, post a question with your code and Ill answer there.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change the channel of the Wifi Direct of your device you need to do the following:

1- Root your phone

2- Download any File manager App: Such as ES File Explorer

3- On ES File Explorer, go to Tools, then turn ON the Root Explorer and click on it then mount RW

4- Using ES File Explorer, go to Device -> Data -> Misc -> Wifi -> p2p_supplicant.conf and change the p2p_oper_channel to whatever channel you want.

5- Turn OFF the Wifi of your phone then turn it ON in order for the change to take place.

You should note that in order for the Wifi direct channel to be the one you did set, the phone needs not to be connected to any Access point when the wifi direct connection starts. Also, usually when phone A connects to phone B via wifi direct, the connection is operating on phone B's channel.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot brother Ziad Halabi, I will try to do so. I have another query regarding this issue that, is there any command I can use in a application to change it? Please let me know.

Comment: The way you can do it is to read all the file using a command, then modify the channel then echo the new String to the file again. Make sure you execute "su"  before doing so. When testing it make sure you backup the file. For the changes to take place you need to turn OFF then ON the WiFi which can be easily done programmatically. Please don't forget to vote up for others to apply this solution.

Comment: Another note is that not all WiFi Direct channels work in all countries so you might assign a channel but see that it is not operating at it.

Comment: I can't really see your code. First your phone needs to be rooted. You cannot access in Java by access a file in the path. You need to create a process that will declare su (super user) and echo to that file by modifying the channel. I advise you to manually open the file and change the channel then write the code to do that.

Comment: I already can change the channel manually. Please see my code at the new questions I've asked:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795510/editing-a-value-in-the-file-p2p-supplicant-conf-which-is-located-on-root-data-m